# How to compare input from process.stdin to string in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, stdin

I'm using nodeJS and I want to be able to pass it commands via stdin. To do this I'm using process.stdin. Ideally I'd have a giant switch with various command strings like "load" or "stop", but I can't get the comparison to work. I've tried slicing out newlines, converting to strings, etc. Can't figure this out, though it seems like it should be fairly simple.

Below is the code I've been trying to get to work:

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();

  if(chunk === null)
    return;

  //i've tried this as well, to no avail
  //chunk = chunk.toString();

  if(chunk == "expectedinput")
    console.log("got it!");

  process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);

});
```

Comment: Are you actually writing to `stdin` or are "load" and "stop" actually command line *arguments*? If you are in fact writing to stdin and you're wanting to provide a kind of "prompt" interface, you may look into utilizing the built-in [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html) module to help with this.

Comment: This would be reading in from stdin to allow commands to be run after the program has started, so args aren't suitable. I'll look into readline, but I'm curious as to why my current solution isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically if you want to read newline-delimited input from stdin, it's easiest to use the built-in [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/readline.html) module.

However for your original code, the problem most likely is either in the chunking of the input and/or that the newline is also captured, so you'd eventually have to either strip it off or change your conditional to something like `if(chunk == "expectedinput\n")` (assuming you have buffered enough input data to see the newline).