# How to compare input from process.stdin to string? Node.js

Tags: node.js, process

I found an answer at the link below, but after using the fixed version of his code it's not working either. It just gives the data back but not the log written in the if statement. If the data matches a string then I want to perform a certain task, I've also tried toString().

[How to compare input from process.stdin to string in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30156588/how-to-compare-input-from-process-stdin-to-string-in-nodejs)

My code

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
    const data = process.stdin.read()
    if (data == 'expected\n') {
        process.stdout.write('worked')
    }
})

process.stdin.on('end', () => {
    process.stdout.write('end')
})
```

His 'fixed' code

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();

  if(chunk === null)
    return;

//i've tried this as well, to no avail
//chunk = chunk.toString();

  if(chunk == "expectedinput\n")
    console.log("got it!");

process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you console.log chunk you will notice that it adds a newline. so what you need to do is split the string by newlines and check the first element.

```
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');

var os = require('os');


process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();

  if(chunk === null)
    return;

  chunk = chunk.split(os.EOL);

  if(chunk[0] == "expectedinput")
    console.log("got it!");

  process.stdout.write('data: ' + chunk);
});
```

or you can use npm module linebyline that makes it easier:

```
var readline = require('linebyline');
var rl = readline.createInterface({
   input: process.stdin,
   output: process.stdout,
   terminal: false
 });

 rl.on('line', function(line){
    if(line == "expectedinput") console.log("got it!");
    console.log(line);
 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry to ask a question inside a question but is the readline module asynchronous?

Comment: its event based, so when theres a new input it emits a event. why you ask?. Also readline is being renamed to linebyline, so you should install it instead of readline.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm using this code to create a p2p messaging app and I need it to be 100% asynchronous